# How to render big object tree in view using angular 4 application?

Tags: angular

I have a requirement in my angular 4 application to render a big object tree. For small object tree, the rendering is fast, but the large object trees, it takes a bit time to load.

If it is a flat structure, I can predict how many items should come in each page. But here, the depth is like 4 or 5 level. I won't be sure, how to break for each page.

Any suggestions could be helpful.